# Flutter - generate toJson method for model including getter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In Flutter we do serialization (toJson) of the model, but how can we generate toJson that includes the getters?

Simple example

```
class MyClass {
  const MyClass({
    required this.a,
    required this.b,
  });
  final double a;
  final double b;

  double get average => (a + b) / 2;
}
```

We use `json_serializable` package for generating the `toJson` method.
It generate the `my_class.g.dart` file where we have toJson and fromJson methods.
The problem is that in this way we do not have a serialization of the getter (`average` field in our example).

What can we do to provide the full serialization including class getters?
Is there a way to achieve it using `json_serializable`, `freezed` or any other package?

Answer (score 3):

Mark your getter with `@JsonKey(includeToJson: true)` annotation. As you can see in the `json_serializable` source code, it's meant to be used both for fields and getters:

```
@Target({TargetKind.field, TargetKind.getter})
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/4.8.1/json_annotation/JsonKey-class.html

Comment: Thank you! In my case I had to annotate with @JsonKey(includeToJson: true) as pure @JsonKey() did not work

Answer (score 0):

annotate getter with

```
@JsonKey(includeToJson: true)
```

Thanks to @Albert221 answer!

Full example:

```
class MyClass {
  const MyClass({
    required this.a,
    required this.b,
  });
  final double a;
  final double b;

  @JsonKey(includeToJson: true)
  double get average => (a + b) / 2;
}
```

Explanation:

In my case adding `@JsonKey()` only did not work.
I had to explicit `includeToJson: true`